# How do I build a C++ program as a .app program?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, xcodebuild

I am trying to build a c++ program I wrote as a stand alone .app that I can distribute. I didn't notice till now that it is just building a unix executable.

I am using Xcode 4.

Also if my program has dependencies on libraries can I package them with the app or do I have to get people to install the libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of program is it: a command-line utility, a full blown application with a GUI, an agent/daemon, a status item, …?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post when trying to make an .app file of my c++ program in Xcode. So these steps might help someone else out.

1. Click Product->Archive in the top menu.
2. Then select the "Distribute..." button (under "Validate...").
3. Select "Export as" and "Application" in the drop down box.
4. Click "Next" and save the file where you want.